# do while loop with a Yes/No user prompt

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Im having issues with my code. The code is to find a factorial of a number, then ask if you want to run the program again, its suppose to run again then exit. However, when I enter `Y` to restart the program it breaks and wont restart and when I enter `N` to exit it wont exit the program.

```java
private static Object Cont;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Greetings
    System.out.println("Welcome to my factorial program! ");
    System.out.println("Please choose from the following: ");

    //Menu
    System.out.println("1. Run Program");
    System.out.println("2. Exit Program");

    int choice = scanner.nextInt();

    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("This program will determine the factorial value of positive integers.");
            do {
                System.out.println("The starting number is 1.");
                System.out.println("Please enter an ending integer value:");
                int n = scanner.nextInt();
                for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                    System.out.println(i + "! = " + fact(i));//call to function
                }
                System.out.println("Run factorial program again? (Y for Yes, N for No): ");
                String Cont = scanner.next();
                if (Cont.equals("N")) {
                    break;
                }
            } while (Cont.equals("Y"));// do while loop
            break;
        //Menu Exit
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Thank you for using the program.");
            System.out.println("Goodbye");
        default:
            System.exit(1); // remebered from last week to set this to one
            System.out.println("Goodbye");
            break;
    }
}//Factorial Math

static long fact(int x) {
    long f = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
        f = f * i;
    }
    return f;
} //End Main Method
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: The root cause of your problem is that you have two distinct `Cont` variables.  The code in the loop assigns to one.  But the `while` condition tests the other one.

Answer (score 0):

You need an additional `break` and declare Cont before the `do` loop:

```java
//private static Object Cont; This is is not declared on the right location, we'll declare it later
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Greetings
    System.out.println("Welcome to my factorial program! ");
    System.out.println("Please choose from the following: ");

    //Menu    
    System.out.println("1. Run Program");
    System.out.println("2. Exit Program");

    int choice = scanner.nextInt();

    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("This program will determine the factorial value of positive integers.");
            String Cont = null; // Cont must be declared here
            do {
                System.out.println("The starting number is 1.");
                System.out.println("Please enter an ending integer value:");
                int n = scanner.nextInt();
                for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                    System.out.println(i + "! = " + fact(i));//call to function
                }
                System.out.println("Run factorial program again? (Y for Yes, N for No): ");
                Cont = scanner.next();
                if (Cont.equals("N")) {
                    break;
                }
            } while (Cont.equals("Y"));// do while loop
            break;
        //Menu Exit
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Thank you for using the program.");
            System.out.println("Goodbye");
            break; // requires this additional break
        default:
            System.exit(1); // remembered from last week to set this to one
            System.out.println("Goodbye");
            break;
    }
}//Factorial Math

static long fact(int x) {
    long f = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
        f = f * i;
    }
    return f;
} //End Main Method
```

Comment: First, there is no need for another break; the existing one is already pointless. If the `if (Cont.equals("N") ...` would be omitted the program flow would be exactly the same.
Consequently, the variable could simply be removed and `scanner.next()` inlined.

Comment: inline is bad practice

Comment: OP's not asking for upper case variables and useless if statements. As you can notice, OP is a new user. Courtesy is important. Please focus on help, not on banter.

Comment: This discussions is exactly why it stoped helping younger coders.

Comment: @MartinNiederl this discussion is not useful to the OP and I won't follow it.

Comment: @stacker I don't understand what there problem is, all I did originally is added additional information to the given answer that the OP may or may not find useful.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems here.

The first problem is that you have declared two distinct `Cont` variables.  The first one is a `static` field.  The second one is a local variable that is declared in the body of the loop.

I don't know why you declared the static field, but I imagine you did it because the `} while (Cont.equals("Y"));` didn't compile without it.  (That is because the `Cont` variable declared in the loop is not in scope outside of the loop's body.)  Unfortunately, it was not the correct solution.  Because, you *now* have code that is assigning to one variable and tests a different one.  Naturally, that doesn't work.

To my mind, the correct solution is to get rid of the `static` field, and the declaration in the loop body.  Than add a declaration for `Cont` *before* the start of the loop.  (It shouldn't have an initialization).  Finally, in the loop you just need to read (using the scanner) and assign a string to `Cont` so that you can test in the loop condition.

---

The second problem is that you have a redundant test in there.  If you are going to test to see if you need to continue using `} while (Cont.equals("Y"));` you don't *also* need to test if `Cont` is `"N"` and `break`.

Relatedly, `equals("Y")` is not the same as not `equals("N")`.  (Consider `"Hello"` ... or `"n"`.  They are neither `"Y"` or `"N"`.) So if you really want to stop the loop when the user types `N`, then the loop termination condition *should* be:

```
    } while (!Cont.equals("N"));  // keep looping while not 'N'
```

---

Finally there are a couple of significant style-related issues.

1. Declaring a `static` field is *usually* a mistake.
2. It is a mistake to use a field when you should be using a local variable.  State that is only relevant to a single execution of a method should be<sup>1</sup> represented using a local variable.
3. It is a major stylistic error for a variable to start with an uppercase letter.  `Cont` should be `cont`.

   If you ever work in a *professional* Java development team that pays attention to style, you will get a hard time for ignoring Java identifiers conventions.  And (IMO) your teacher *should* dock style marks for this mistake.

<sup>1 - Reasons:  1) It makes the method harder to read because the variable declaration is further away from its use.  2) It typically makes the code non-reentrant.  3) It opens you up to unwanted coupling between methods; e.g. if two methods accidentally share the same "local variable declared as a field".  4) In many cases it uses more memory.</sup>